# php xml - php not outputting xml file even though all code appears to be correct, can you spot an error?

Tags: php, xml

php xml - php not outputting xml file even though all code appears to be correct, can you spot an error?

Hello I am practising XML and I wis  to output it through php. This is the php code I wish to output xml file from:

```
<?php
    $xml_file = 'MusicMix.xml';            

    //load the content of the XML file and create a new XML object
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
    foreach ($xml->musicmix as $musicmix) {
            echo $musicmix->playlist_id,  ' - ';
            echo $musicmix->name, '<br />';
            echo $musicmix->category, '<br />';
            echo $musicmix->song_id, '<br />';
            echo $musicmix->songname, '<br />';
    }
    ?>

This is the XML code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<musicmix>
    <playlist_id>W12345</playlist_id>
    <name>GymOne</name>
    <category>Rock</category>
        <song_id>123455</song_id>
            <songname>rockthisone</songname>
        <song_id>454545</song_id>
            <songname>rocksomemore</songname>
    <playlist_id>W34567</playlist_id>
    <name>SleepOne</name>
    <category>
    Classical
    </category>
        <song_id>144455</song_id>
            <songname>niceone</songname>
        <song_id>444445</song_id>
            <songname>nicerone</songname>
</musicmix>
```

Comment: _code appears to be correct_ Err no

Comment: You should have two musicmix tag, i'l post a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
The issue was that I was calling the php from the wrong variable so I was pointing the code in the wrong direction: here is the correct code, I changed 'musicmix' to playlist in the foreach loop and all other variables and it is now working:

```
<?php
$xml_file = 'MusicMix.xml';            

//load the content of the XML file and create a new XML object
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
foreach ($xml->playlist as $playlist) {
        echo $playlist->playlist_id,  ' - ';
        echo $playlist->name, '<br />';
        echo $playlist->category, '<br />';
        echo $playlist->song_id, '<br />';
        echo $playlist->songname, '<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you should have a xml structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
    <musicmix>
        <playlist_id>W12345</playlist_id>
        <name>GymOne</name>
        <category>Rock</category>
        <song_id>123455</song_id>
        <songname>rockthisone</songname>
        <song_id>454545</song_id>
        <songname>rocksomemore</songname>
    </musicmix>
    <musicmix>
        <playlist_id>W34567</playlist_id>
        <name>SleepOne</name>
        <category>
            Classical
        </category>
        <song_id>144455</song_id>
        <songname>niceone</songname>
        <song_id>444445</song_id>
        <songname>nicerone</songname>
    </musicmix>
</collection>
```

Then you can read its data like you did already:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
foreach ($xml->musicmix as $musicmix) {
    echo $musicmix->playlist_id, ' - ';
    echo $musicmix->name, '<br />';
    echo $musicmix->category, '<br />';
    echo $musicmix->song_id, '<br />';
    echo $musicmix->songname, '<br />';
}
```

Tested and it works.